# Why is portlet not displayed under sample category in liferay 7?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I have created a portlet in liferay 7. I built and deployed portlet successfully. The portlet is displayed successfully. But when I imported a class of another project into this portlet, the status of the portlet turned into installed rather than active, and the portlet disappears from the sample category. Any idea where might I go wrong? Please help..Thanx in advance..

Comment: As on many of your other questions: Please don't crosspost, or - at least - crosslink your crossposts. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site

Comment: There is probably a missing dependency. [Go into the Gogo Shell](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/reference/-/knowledge_base/7-0/using-the-felix-gogo-shell) and execute `diag <number of your portlet bundle>` and put the result here. Also, `scr:info <full name of your portlet class>` should give us some good information.